# SDL2 Fullscreen resolution issue (extending render over second screen)

Tags: c++, sdl, fullscreen, sdl-2, monitor

[image]

I am using multiple monitors on my PC. One of them is a TV. When I launch my application on my regular monitors, the application gets scaled properly.

However, when I run the application in fullscreen on my TV, the resolution will be too large and the output shows partially on another screen (see the blue colored output in my screenshot).

The TV is connected via HDMI and uses the same resolution as the other screens (1920x1080). It seems to be a software issue, because the output is partially visible on another screen.

I am using the following code to toggle fullscreen mode:

```
SDL_SetWindowFullscreen( m_Window, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN );
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

When I make the TV my main display in Windows, it seems to fit properly on the TV. However, it still shows partially on the other screen (but this time it shows twice) and the mouse positioning is incorrect on the TV. Maybe the resolution is changed differently?

**UPDATE 2**

Windows 10 allows font sizes to be changed on a monitor. This is why my resolution detection in SDL2 identified a different resolution for my TV. Now I need to find a way to work around this.

[image]

Comment: can you show your code which does this job?

Comment: @pergy I updated my question

Comment: Have you tried with `SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(m_Window, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP)` yet?

Comment: @pergy Yes I have. However, it gives a similar effect. The fullscreen starts halfway my TV and overlaps the other monitor.

Comment: and where is the window's position when the fullscreen in toggled? mb you should put it on TV screen first (`SDL_SetWindowPosition`)

Comment: @pergy Please also see my update in my question

Comment: yeah, even more strange :) `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` should use the display's resolution, so I see no reason why it shows up on secondary display when your TV is set as main display

Comment: You suggestion seems to work. Thank you very much! When I use `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP` combined with `SDL_SetWindowPosition`, it will fit on one screen without overlapping to other screens. However, it will always display on the main screen. I cannot move it to another screen to put the fullscreen on that screen anymore. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: SDL will take every display into account for positioning. Eg. if you have 2 pieces of 1920x1080 displays, area from (0,0) to (1920,1080) will be your display on the left and area from (1920,0) to (3840,1080) will be your second display. `SDL_SetWindowPosition` should be able to put your window on any display using the proper coordinates

Comment: @pergy Thank you very much! I have just one question. I am trying to program the application so that it automatically uses fullscreen on the current display using `SDL_GetDisplayBounds`. The idea is working, but my TV is detected to use a resolution of 1537 x 865, while in fact it uses 1920x1080. That is why it will eventually position on a wrong position. This might be why it was not positioning correctly in the first place?

Comment: @pergy Okay I found the issue. It has to do with Windows 10 font sizes. I'll post the image in my answer. Now I need to find out how to fix this

Comment: I've found the same bug on win10 with text scaling